# trying to use yum to install git in linux

Tags: linux

```
$ sudo yum install git
CentOS Linux 8 - AppStream                      0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'appstream':
  - Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for http://vault.centos.orgcentos/8/AppStream/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml [Could not resolve host: vault.centos.orgcentos]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'appstream': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

Comment: Are you trying this behind a proxy? Have you tried to install other packages?

Comment: Apart from the fact that I don't see a question here, it looks as if there's an error in your yum configuration. Your system is trying to contact `vault.centos.orgcentos`, which isn't a valid hostname. You may want to investigate your repository configuration in `/etc/yum.repos.d`.

Comment: I'm trying to use yum to install git and that was my error. Do you know the commands to switch what you were recommending? Sorry, I am pretty new to Linux

Comment: CentOS 8 had 'End Of Life' Dec 31 - 2021. .... If you want updates, etc. package installs, please migrate to Rocky Linux 8 https://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/migrate-from-centos-8-to-rocky-linux-conversion/

Comment: A valid repo URL must include a `repodata/` folder, like https://vault.centos.org/8.5.2111/BaseOS/x86_64/os/ ......... Examples, edited CentOS repo files https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cqafM9dnGZNgUBm5ozKNR9EhOkFbLLEs?usp=sharing